# Is it possible that $P(A\cap B)$ is greater than $P(A)$ or $P(B)$?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> Is it possible that $P(A\cap B)$ is greater than $P(A)$ or $P(B)$?

I think not.
Let's assume WLOG that $P(A\cap B) > P(A)$. Then,
$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)} > \frac{P(A)}{P(A)} = 1$$

Contradiction.

Is my proof valid?

Comment: Your proof works. Another simpler proof is $P(A)=P(A \cap B)+(A \setminus B) \ge P(A \cap B)$ (this is simpler because it does not use Bayes formula, which is not obvious).

Comment: @Crostul, Continuing your proof: $P(A) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\setminus B) > P(A) + p(A \setminus B)$. And we got that $P(A\setminus B) < 0$. Contradiction.

Comment: Your proof is not valid. It does not work for $P(A)=0$.

Comment: @drhab, you're right. Technically I could show that $P(A) = 0 \implies P(A\cap B) = 0$ and so it couldn't be greater than $P(B)$ and we're done.

Comment: Somehow you are interchanging the question: "can it happen that $P(A\cap B)>P(A)$?" for the question: "can it happen that $P(B|A)>1$?". It is not so that the answer on the second question (no) has more "authority"  than the answer on the first (also no).

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A basic requirement for a probability measure is that if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint events, then $P(X\cup Y)=P(X)+P(Y)$.

Since $A=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$, where $A\setminus B$ and $A\cap B$ are disjoint,
$$
P(A)=P(A\setminus B)+P(A\cap B)\ge P(A\cap B)
$$

---

About your proof: it is correct once you know that $P(B\mid A)\le 1$, but this is a consequence of $P(A\cap B)\le P(A)$, so your argument is circular.

Comment: Glad to meet you, @egreg!

Comment: @Covvar Actually, $P(B\mid A)\le 1$ follows from $P(A\cap B)\le P(A)$, so you can't use it.

Comment: +1) Exactly! $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)$ allows us to give a proper definition of $P(B|A)$ in such a way that $P(.|A)$ can be recognized as a probability measure.

Comment: No, it follows from the fact that any probability, of any event is $\le 1$. That is elementary, he can use it.

Comment: @JimmyR. The OP only noticed that - if $P(A\cap B)>P(A)$ would be true in some cases - we would run into trouble by the usual way of defining of $P(.|A)$: it cannot in all cases be recognized as a probability measure anymore. That on its own is no proof of the fact that $P(A\cap B)>P(A)$ is false. It proves at most that we must seek for another definition of $P(.|A)$. Fortunately we don't have to, because $P(A\cap B)>P(A)$ can be shown to be false on other grounds.

Comment: @drhab Ok, yes, I see.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\cap B\subseteq B$.

(What you did is correct, but is not the shortest way to do it.)

Comment: Correct? I disagree with that. See my comments on the question.

Comment: @drhab It certainly is more elementary that any probability is less or equal than $1$ and the OP uses this to lead to a contradiction his assumption. The contradiction is not about $B\mid A$, it is about a/any probability being $>1$. I think that I understand your comment and your objection, but I still think it is correct what he did.

Comment: $P(B)\leq1$ is more elementary, yes. But $P(B|A)\leq1$ is not. This because $P(.|A)$ can be only defined as a probability measure *by the grace of* $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)$.

Comment: It is indeed not trivial that $Q(\cdot):=P(\cdot \mid A )=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$ is a probability measure and one needs to show this, you are right. But in the proof one does not use that $P(A\cap B)\le P(A)$. It is immediate that $Q\ge0$ and one shows that $Q(A)=\frac{P(A)}{P(A)}1$, hence for any other set $E$, $Q(E)\le Q(A)=1$. And additivity does not make I use (I think). I agree that the way the OP choosed is not a good one, and he should have it done in a much simpler way, but still I think it is correct. Perhaps I am still wrong though, thanks a lot for your feedback. @drhab

Comment: "hence for any other set $Q(E)\leq Q(A)=1$". This is not just falling from the sky, but is a direct consequence of $P(A\cap E)\leq P(A\cap A)=P(A)$. Cheers. Thanks a lot too.

Answer (score 1):

If that were true, for $A =B, \, \,P(A) >P(A)$.And that can't happen, hence false.

Comment: The question is: "can it happen?". Not "will it always happen?" (hence also in the special case you mention).

Comment: When it happens, it happens for any A and B. Had I said, it doesn't happen for given case so it doesn't happen for all, that would have been wrong.

Comment: You only showed that it cannot happen in special case $A=B$. That is not enough. It does not exclude that it might happen in other cases.

Comment: No, I said if actual proposition had happened, my special case would also have been true.

Comment: Then what is your interpretation of that proposition?

Comment: The question is: “Is it possible that $P(A\cap B)$ is greater than $P(A)$ and $P(B)$?”. It is not “Is $P(A\cap B)>P(A)$ for all $A$ and $B$?”